# Two triangles in double perspective are in triple perspective.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Is this right?:

Let be $\triangle ABC, \triangle A_1B_1C_1$ and centers of perspective $x, x_1$ such that $x = AA_1 . BB_1.CC_1$ and $x_1= BC_1.A_1B.AC_1$ then by papus dual the lines $AC_1, A_1C, BA_1, A_1B, CB_1, BC_1$ are colinear in a point(other center of perspective), then the triangles are in triple perspective.